# The contact info like name phone no. is going above the page. How to bring it closer to the Objective section?

Tags: formatting, moderncv

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\textheight=8in  
\enlargethispage*{-2\baselineskip}

\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{textcomp,xpatch}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1.15in}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}

\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{\itshape#3}{#3}{}{}
\name{My}{Name}
\phone[mobile]{+123456789}           \email{mynamegmail.com}  
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Objective}
\item{To secure a Research Assistantship position after my graduation in a field relating to my area of interest}
```

[image]

Comment: You're chaning `\voffset`. Why? You're also making a bunch of document size changes (`\enlargethispage` + adjusting `\textheight` + `scale=0.75` in [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry))... why?

Answer (score 2):

The class `moderncv` uses package `geometry` to define the writing area and margins.

Please do not disturb `geometry` by using commands like `\textheight=8in`!

Please see the following code (I commented your commands not needed with `geometry`)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
%\textheight=8in  
%\enlargethispage*{-2\baselineskip}

\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75,
  showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{textcomp,xpatch}

%\setlength{\voffset}{-1.15in}
%\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}

\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{\itshape#3}{#3}{}{}
\name{My}{Name}
\phone[mobile]{+123456789}           
\email{myname@gmail.com}  


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Objective}
\cvitem{To secure a Research Assistantship position after my graduation in a field relating to my area of interest}{test}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

To change the layout of your cv simply use the parameter package  `geometry` offers (read the documentation with `texdoc geometry` typed on your terminal/console).

For example you can use option `top=1cm` to get less space before the start of your cv:

```
\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75,
  headsep=5pt, % <======================================================
  top=1cm, % <==========================================================
  showframe
]{geometry}
```

With this changes in code for `geometry` you get

[image: with other layout]

You can change several parameters/options for your need, just read the documentation of `geometry` ...